# android - stopping multiple threads inside service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I have an activity with two checkboxes named **images** and **videos**. In my service i am running two threads against these two checkboxes name **imagethread** and **videothread**. If user checks the  images checkbox i am starting the service and starting the image thread. and if user uncheck it i am stopping the service.so i want to do if user uncheck the box, stop the service and stop the thread too .so now two problems i am having

1. i am not able to stop the thread inside a service
2. for example if user uncheck the video checkbox how can i identify in my **onDestroy()** method that audio checkbox is checked so now stop the audio thread but not image because it is checked.

here is my code snipped of my first problem

```
public synchronized void onDestroy() 
{   
    image_thread_running = false;
    super.onDestroy();

    if(image_thread_running){
        system.out.println("stop thread"); //message is successfully printing on a console
        imageThread.interrupt(); //its not working.

    }

}

public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    image_thread_running = true;
    this.intent = intent;


    String myString = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("image"))
    {
        if(image_thread_running){
            imageThread.start();

        }


    }else if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("audio")){
        audioThread.start();
    }
}

class ImageThread extends Thread
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    { 


        if (image_thread_running){
            System.out.println("Service running");
            try {
                if(checkInternetConnection()){
                    UploadFiles();
                    Thread.sleep(interval);
                }else{
                    Log.d("msg","internet is not connected");
                } 


            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {



            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

so for example if i get successful in getting above code works means thread is stopping successfully,so it leads to me second problem which is now how can i identify that there is a message from video checkbox to stop the video thread. because by changing bool value in `onDestroy()` will leads to change both bool value image_thread_running and video_thread_running . hope you understand my problem

Comment: Why do you start both a `Service` and a `Thread`? Why not just the `Thread` directly?

Comment: @nkn i was first used the threads and then async task but my app become slow and sometimes crashes by giving the message force close or not responding because i am uploading big files on the server. so service is better for this

Answer (score 0):

There's been a time that `.stop()` has been deprecated an highly discouraged as it might terminate your `Thread` in an unsafe way.

The most common approach is having a `boolean` controller inside your `Thread`, which will check if some action happened (in your case, a checkbox has been checked/unchecked), and if so, in the next loop iteration, simply use `return` within your `Thread`. This will terminate it cleanly and safely. You can even use it to stop the service, so if you exit the `Thread`, it would mean that you have to exit the `Service` too.

Suppose this is your `CheckBox`'s `onClickListener()`:

```
boolean is_checked = false;

cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);

cb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do the stuff your need
    is_checked = v.isChecked();
  }
}); 

new Thread(
  new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
      while (is_checked) {
        // Do your stuff here...

        ...
      }
      // If you've reached this point, it means you have unchecked
      // the checkbox since the value of is_checked is false
      // return will exit your Thread, prior to it, you could simply stop
      // your service also.
      ...
      return;
    }
  }
).start();
```

Comment: If you were going to take this approach you would need to mark is_checked as volatile, or use an AtomicBoolean instead. A better approach would be to give the thread its own private boolean that can be get/set via synchronized methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the thread handle interruption -- in other words, the thread must recognize that you called interrupt and do whatever is necessary to exit from the thread.

```
void run() {
    while(!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
        // do work
    }
}
```

The `InterruptedException` will only occur if an interruptible method such as `Thread.sleep()` or `Thread.wait()` was being performed in the thread. Otherwise, it effectively just sets a flag that you can check with `Thread.interrupted()` or `Thread.isInterrupted()`.

So you need to check the status from within the thread to see if it has been interrupted, in order for the `interrupt()` calls to have an effect.

This is explained very clearly at [Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/).

> Every thread has a Boolean property associated with it that represents
>   its interrupted status. The interrupted status is initially false;
>   when a thread is interrupted by some other thread through a call to
>   Thread.interrupt(), one of two things happens. If that thread is
>   executing a low-level interruptible blocking method like
>   Thread.sleep(), Thread.join(), or Object.wait(), it unblocks and
>   throws InterruptedException. Otherwise, interrupt() merely sets the
>   thread's interruption status. Code running in the interrupted thread
>   can later poll the interrupted status to see if it has been requested
>   to stop what it is doing; the interrupted status can be read with
>   Thread.isInterrupted() and can be read and cleared in a single
>   operation with the poorly named Thread.interrupted().

That page also explains how to handle `InterruptedException`.

---

For the kind of work you seem to be doing in the image thread (uploading files), I'd recommend using an `IntentService` instead. Using IntentService will also decouple the task from your activity's lifecycle, so for example it can continue across orientation changes, or complete its work after the user navigates to a different activity. Unlike a `Service`, an `IntentService` runs in a separate thread, and handling the worker thread is taken care of for you. (You can also easily implement a queue of tasks, or chain from one task to another, simply by handling different actions in `onHandleIntent`.)

Comment: thankyou for your detailed answer .so then you mean if user decided to uncheck the box because he decided to not to upload the images then what advice you will give me .. should i use then thread.sleep or wait?

Comment: and what about my second question that if user uncheck the other check box how can i check that event so that i can stop or pause 2nd thread not first

Comment: What kind of work are you doing in these threads? Is it ongoing work that needs a persistent thread? Or is it a single task or series of tasks? If it's the latter you might be better served using IntentService or BlockingQueue. As for how to handle the two checkboxes, since you're using two separate threads, simply make the appropriate thread stop based on either the isInterrupted() status in that thread, or giving each thread a method which sets a private boolean flag indicating that the thread should stop doing work.